# What is the syntax of 'file.names' argument in transNcdfMerge function of ncdf.tools

Tags: r, netcdf

What is the syntax of `file.names` argument in `transNcdfMerge` function of `ncdf.tools`?

It's returning error

> "Error: unexpected symbol in "transNcdfMerge (3B43.19980701.7.SUB.nc"

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example? The help file of `?transNcdfMerge` says it should be a character vector of file names.

Comment: @Vandenman `transNcdfMerge (c(3B43.19980701.7.SUB.nc, 3B43.19990701.7.SUB.nc),  name.change = function(x) return(x),time.diff = NULL, fun.start = NULL, fun.end = NULL, time.range.out = NULL, format = "%Y%m,convert = function(x) chron(paste(x, "15",sep = ""), format = "ymd", out.format = "d-m-y"), path.target = getwd(), target.name = "out.nc")`